# Select even if count=0 mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count

So I have 3 tables:

```
 accident, involve and car. 
 Car (registration_nr, model,year)
 involve (licence_nr,registration_nr (FK of car), raport_nr (FK of accident))
 accident(raport_nr, date)
```

I have to count the number of accidents for each car model from Jan 1,2014 but must select also the cars with count 0 (that from jan 01,2014 haven't been in an accident) This is the difficult part for me , till now I can select only those that have been in an accident.

```
Select c.model,count(m.registration_nr)
from car as c
join involve as i
on i.registration_nr=c.registration_nr
join  accident as a
on i.raport_nr=a.raporti_nr 
where a._date between '2014-01-01' and curdate() 
group by c.model;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly stating that you only want rows with accidents:

```
where a._date between '2014-01-01' and curdate()
```

Just add an `OR` clause to allow records where `a._date IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
Select c.model, sum(a._date between '2014-01-01' and curdate() )
from car c left join
     involve i
     on i.registration_nr = c.registration_nr left join
     accident a
     on i.raport_nr = a.raporti_nr 
group by c.model;
```

I also added `left join`s -- just in case some models have no accidents at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem and it took me very long to figure it out.
It turned out that the aggregate function COUNT will return 0 if the collection is all NULL. So here is how you would put the query:

```
SELECT model, COUNT(registration_nr)
FROM car LEFT JOIN (involve NATURAL JOIN accident) USING (registration_nr)
WHERE date > '01-01-2014' OR date IS NULL
GROUP BY model
```

In my case, the output would be something like:

```
Model     Count
Mazda     1
Honda     0
```